# Find first Facebook message in a thread

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there a way to search or arrive at the first Facebook message in a thread without scrolling back for hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No absolute way actually. The best bet is to remember your first message and then search it on the search bar of that conversation. Even if you don't remember, a simple search with `hi` will save you ~50 scroll ups(As I'm assuming they'll show the first occurrence of `hi` as the result).

[image]

> P.S. I found my first message to a thread with thousands of messages
>   in 3 to 4 try with this method. :)

Comment: This works. I got back to my first message in 2005

Answer (score 6):

Here's exactly how to do it:

> To start, go to http://m.facebook.com/messages/
>
> Then click the person you want to see the first message with.
> right click the ”See older messages” button and click “open in new tab” or something that relates to that depending on what browser you use. Now, the link will appear in a new tab and it should look something like this:
>
> http://m.facebook.com/messages/read/?forward=0&start=52695&page_size=7&tids=numbers=inbox&tid=numbers&see_older=1&refid=12
>
> From here, all you have to do is change the `start=52695` (yours will be another number) to `start=` a low number like 200 And that’s it! You will still have to click ”See older messages” a bit to get through those 100-200 messages, but it’s nothing compared to going through 50,000 messages first!

Source: http://jcoinster.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/finally-how-to-see-your-first-facebook-messages-with-someone/

Comment: This works for me in 2016

Answer (score -2):

by the looks you now have to use the m. version of the site and you remove the "&last_message_timestamp=[0-9]+" section from the older messages link as well as changing "start=[0-9]+" to be the message you want to see (note [0-9]+ meaning a number of some kind) method is similar I recommend using copy link and then editing but it should still work with a new tab.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to have an app that scrolls for you.
Check this out, with legit youtube video:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rock-and-scroll/gpbflbhgfmdfobkcmplmiflfminmoiko